# Using assembly from subfolder

Tags: .net, dll

This is the situation (i cannot change this approach, just looking for a solution):

- AppFolder\StartApp.exe
- AppFolder\General.dll
- AppFolder\Bll\Business.dll
- AppFolder\Bll\General.dll

The StartApp.exe is instantiating a class in Business.dll (with CreateInstance),
and runs a method within that class.
It turns out that we always use the General.dll from the AppFolder, but we really need to use the General.dll in the Bll folder (which is the newest version)

Comment: What prevent you from deleting the old reference of General.dll from your exe and adding the new version?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`<probing>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb.aspx) and  [`<codebase>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb.aspx)  element in the configuration to specify the path of assembly

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

[How to locate runtime assemblies - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

How about not directly using the `Activator.CreateInstance` but rather use `Assembly.LoadFrom` to load the assembly and then iterate over `GetTypes` to locate the Type you want to instantiate. Once you get the type, the apply `Activator.CreateInstance`.

As far as I remember the type loaded in this way will cause `Appdomain.AssemblyResolve` event for the DLLs that it needs. Handle that event and feed the dependent assembly yourself. This will bypass the DLL lying in the application folder.

Just give it a try. Ample documentation is available on the net on `AssemblyResolve` and `LoadFrom` context.